# TeleBot, ошибка при отправке текста

Tags: python, строки, telebot

Хочу отправить InlineKeyboardMarkup, используя данный код:

```
def sendBoard(self):
    bot.send_message(self.host_id, 'This is board:', reply_markup=self.board)
    bot.send_message(self.guest_id, 'This is board:', reply_markup=self.board)
```

Однако текст не воспринимается и говорит, что это вовсе не строка.

Текст ошибки:

```
2018-11-01 17:08:36,068 (__init__.py:417 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\'t parse inline keyboard button: Field \\"text\\" must be of type String"}']"
```

При это данный участок кода

```
elif message.text == 'Button':
    keys = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keys.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='B1', callback_data='111'))
    keys.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='B2', callback_data='222'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Buttons?', reply_markup=keys)
```

успешно отправляет сообщение.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ошибка была не с текстом сообщения, а с текстом кнопки.

Comment: А можно подробнее о том что за проблема была и как ее решили?

Comment: Ошибка, указанная здесь: Bad Request: can\'t parse inline keyboard button: Field \\"text\\" must be of type String"}']" была не из-за текста сообщения, а из-за текста InlineKeyBoardButton, так как в совершенно другом месте при создании кнопок была допущена ошибка.